# How can I find out what is populating an <input> tag

Tags: javascript, web, post, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to find out what happens when I log into a website, using Firefox Web Developer Tools. One of the steps that happen automatially is a POST form submission:

```
<form name="login" [...] <input type="hidden" name="pm_fp" id="pm_fp" /> </form>
```

The network tab in Web Developer Tools tells me that an actual value is submitted for `pm_fp`,

`pm_pf: "version[...]"`

I'm not very experienced with web development, but I assume this is populated programmatically by some javascript somewhere. The form seems to be submitted by

```
<body onload="get_deviceprint(); document.login.submit();">
```

I searched for these functions with Cntrl+Shift+F in the Debugger to add a breakpoint, but no luck.

How can I find out what is populating the `pm_fp` value? I'd like as specific instructions as possible, since I have limited experience with web development and Web Developer Tools.

Comment: I'm more familiar with chrome developer tools than firefox, but if a POST request is happening then perhaps check the network tab and see what the request was, your answer might be there?

Comment: Thanks @David, the network tab is where I see the value of pm_fp which I mentioned. I’ll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: umm, can't you see which `js` file has reference of `pm_fp` using the good old ctrl+f on the source? investigative works involving an already running code needs a lot of time and manual labor yes.

Comment: If you’re still looking, it’s probably going to be most helpful to look at the source JavaScript, rather than the html markup. If the website uses a framework like react, Vue or angular (probably one of them) then the source will be where you find the variable names.

Comment: `<body onload="get_deviceprint(); document.login.submit();">` indicates that the login happens directly when the page is loaded. Is that the case?